# how to determine if your DD-WRT router has been compromised?

Tags: dd-wrt

I've got a DD-WRT router that is running a very old build. Due to a few exploits over the past couple of years, I'm concerned about the integrity of the device.   Before I flash to a newer version of the firmware, how would I go about checking if the router's existing OS has been compromised?

Comment: Personally, I'd back up the config and flash the firmware anyway. You've got so many possible places to look that it would become onorous.

Answer (score 3):

There's no one size fits all way to check for compromises, since by nature a compromise looks legitimate to the router.

Your best bets are to check traffic logs trying to access the web interface, SSH port or Telnet. Even if they didn't exploit that specific mechanism, it might give you some identification for a machine that is trying to compromise your router, which you can then narrow down.

If you're concerned about any potential compromise continuing, make sure you take your router off the network before flashing, and then make sure to purge NVRAM (if the device uses it) and use new login credentials/authentication for the router in future, preferably secure ones.